# Not enough VRAM?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

So I am experiencing the following problem for the first time - on my work rig I have a single gtx 1080 which is 8gbs of VRAM. On my current project ( I work with CAD files don't be supriced of the size) I have hit a vram limitation at 4,7gb.
[image: Out of VRAM - 4,7gb out of 8]

Now, before being asked - I have nothing else opened other than Chrome and Spotify as I took this screencap. Yes, I have already tuned the render settings for light paths. The only thing I could think of being problematic is the HDRi I use for lighting, so I'll change it. First trying to reduce the "Map Resolution" did nothing, same as before, same vram usage.
[image: 1k HDRi change]

Now I changed it from a 4k HDRi to a 1k HDRi. Only difference is in -40mb vram.
Can anyone give me advice on how to fix this? I have a TitanX I can test this scene on, however I wish to use my 1070s to render it faster.

Comment: 40 million faces is indeed a lot, add on top of that the size of your textures and who knows what else you have on your scene (particles? Volumetrics? Lots of Subsurf?). When you run out of vRAM it means exactly that: no more memory on your GPU. Try simplifying the scene/geometry/shaders/textures, bake as much a you can, etc... Split the scene in different layers that are renderable, save the images as EXR and combine them later in the compositor. See: [How to Render a Complex Scene without it Crashing](https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/how-to-render-a-complex-scene-without-crashing).

Comment: Thank you for reminding me that! I know, however the question comes from "why is 4.7gb=crash when I got a total of 8gb?". Will try splitting and post my results.

Comment: I did try splitting in render layers. Yes, when doing stills there is no problem, but what I do are animations. As I mentioned before the large poly count is because of raw CAD files, SolidWorks to be precise, imported to 3ds Max with reduced quality and exported/imported as .fbx. I have found this approach very good, however - first time I run out of memory.